# .NET Core app targeting full framework - Stopped working in IIS

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core, port

We have a ASP.NET Core MVC application that targets `net461` due to requiring Entity Framework for Oracle.
Up until recently, this application has been working fine on both our DEV and QA servers.

We are deploying it as a self-contained app, but also have .NET Core runtime and  the ASP.NET Core IIS hosting bundle installed on the servers.

Recently, we started running into issues after deployment where the application will not start up. In the browser, we get [502.5 Process Failure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.2#5025-process-failure).
On the server, the only error we can find is in the Windows event logs: `Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/DEFAULT WEB SITE/<appname>' with physical root 'D:\path\' created process with commandline 'D:\path\<appname>.exe ' but failed to listen on the given port '<randomport>'`.

Various SO posts and articles I have found say this is usually due to a different runtime version installed on the server vs. the client.

1. This is self-contained so the runtime is bundled, so I'm not sure that is the issue.
2. We have not changed what is installed on our development PCs OR on the servers, but have tried uninstalling and re-installing the runtime on the servers.
3. Since this targets the full framework `net461` does it even matter the .NET Core version? Or does only the .NET version matter?

We have some people thinking the issue is with it obtaining a port to listen on. I have tried adding `.UseUrls()` in `Program.cs` and adding in Kestrel ports in `appSettings.json` but nothing makes any difference and we still get the same error.

To make matters more confusing, our current build runs fine on the QA server now but fails to start in DEV. Sometimes we try to publish and it works in one environment but not the other, and sometimes it fails in both. We are following the same deployment steps and the only differences are config files.

We have tried `<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>` and without.

We have tried publishing from VS and from `dotnet publish`.

We have tried `net stop was /y` `net start w3svc`.

We even had the server restored to an earlier point before these issues started.

As of now, we can't find any pattern to when/why some deployments will run and some will fail. Is there anyone who can provide some input on this?

Comment: It sounds like the app is throwing an exception during startup. Try opening a command prompt to the published app directory and running `dotnet MyApp.dll`. If you see any exceptions logged to the console window, please update your question with those, along with the stack traces.

Comment: It is an .exe file, so there is no .dll. If I try this locally, it takes a minute but eventually starts up. If I try it on the server, it just hangs and nothing shows in the console window.

Comment: Sorry. I read that, but it didn't sink in. Running the exe has the same effect of what I was looking for though. If it's hanging, you might be timing out on a connection or something. You might need to add some more extensive logging around your `Startup` class.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. If I set `stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"` in my web.config, log files are created there but are never written to. I'll manually try some `File.WriteAllText()`s and see if I can't get anything that way.

Comment: `ILoggerFactory` is a hosting service, so it can be injected into `Startup` (as well as more specific logging interfaces such as `ILogger<Startup>`). In short, you can add an `ILogger<Startup>` param to your `Startup` constructor, save it to an ivar and then utilize it in `ConfigureServices` and `Configure`. That should make your logging efforts much easier.

Comment: We are using Serilog currently, but I don't think it's getting far enough in to even start application logging. We shall see.

Comment: The logging provider and levels can be customized per namespace. I'd add something to log Debug and higher (basically everything) to console (which is a logging provider included by default) for `YourApp.Startup`. Then, you shouldn't need to worry about things like Serilog. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-filtering

Comment: Found the problem. On application startup, we are scheduling some things using [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler). On had a start/end time that must be confusing the library. It causes it to freeze up entirely without throwing an exception. Removing/changing the time fixed or issue! Thank you!!!

Comment: No problem. Glad you found it.

Comment: If you found the cause, post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On application startup, we are scheduling some things using FluentScheduler. On had a start/end time that must be confusing the library. It causes it to freeze up entirely without throwing an exception. Removing/changing the time fixed or issue!

Comment: I have a very similar problem. How do you solved it

Comment: Log statements. Put them everywhere in Program.cs and Startup.cs and log things to file. From there we just looked at what did and didn't log to narrow down where it was stopping.

Comment: But I’m not using that’s library that you mentioned. I will try with the logs

Comment: could this be a problem ?  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1) and then in the server with IIS where deployed my app i have installed the latest version of .NET Core 2.2 Runtime & Hosting Bundle for Windows (v2.2.3)

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm really not sure. You may want to search around and see if someone has asked a similar question, or ask your own question if you can't find it. To the best of my knowledge though, what you are describing should still work. Again though, I am no expert here.